# To get a library file in synopsys using open command

Tags: parsing, tcl, .lib

Hi I am using the following code to get data from a library file which is generated from synopsys. I am using tcl to code.

```
set file [open "my_file.lib r]
set final [read -nonewline $file]
close $file
```

This code is not working for me. It is a library file so I want to know if there is error in my code or in the library. Please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by **not working**? Is there any error? What are your goals here? Looking at the code, you are trying to read the contents of a file, but what really are your goals?

Comment: Ya i am trying to read the file so that I can get the required selected data from the file and use it for sorting. I will have to use a while or for loop to fetch the required data from the file. Thats my aim. This code is not recognizing the file at all. So I dont knw if the code is wrong or some issue with the file.

Comment: I am sorry, but what did you meant by **not recognize the file**? Is it file not found?

Comment: What _exact_ error message is it producing, if any?

Answer (score 1):

use this to read .lib file

set file [open "filename.lib" r] #or if u are in another folder from file directory then use full path of the .lib file

set filedata [read $file]

puts "$filedata"

close $file

Answer (score 0):

What is a "library file"? is it just text or is it a binary file? If it has binary data, you could do this:

```
set filename my_file.lib
set file [open $filename r]
fconfigure $file -translation binary
set final [read $file [file size $filename]]
close $file
```

Comment: The error I am getting is the following :  no such file or directory
        Use error_info for more info. (CMD-013)
The library is text file and it is pretty huge.

Comment: use `[file exists]` before trying to open it. If it's huge, are you sure you need to read the whole thing into memory?